# Apache: NE Flag (no escape) Not Working in RewriteRule of mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, urlencode, urldecode

I have a URL like this:

```
http://www.sample.com/do/example/v1/abcd
```

I want to redirect it to:

```
http://sub.sample.com/some/test/do/example/v1/abcd
```

So I create an `.htaccess` file and using **RewriteRule** to do this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?sample\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/do/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://sub.sample.com/some/test/do/%1
```

Everything works fine until the "abcd" is change to "PjX7%2Bj69" that has the %2B escaped character. So with this URL:

```
http://www.sample.com/do/example/v1/PjX7%2Bj69
```

I get:

```
404 Not Found | The requested URL do/example/v1/PjX7+j69 was not found on this server.
```

As we notice, the Apache changes the "**PjX7%2Bj69**" parameter to "**PjX7+j69**". So I use the `NE Flag` to disable the decoding:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://sub.sample.com/some/test/do/%1 [NE]
```

But it is not working.

How can I prevent Apache URL decoding?

Answer (score 0):

That is not what the [`NE` flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_ne) is for.

Those paths should be equivalent, anyway, because you should be decoding those sequences at the subdomain. If you *really* can't correct that, which I think is the real issue, you can instead work with the original, undecoded URL:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?sample\.com$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^\S+\s+/do/(.*)\s
RewriteRule ^ http://sub.sample.com/some/test/do/%1 [R,END]
```